# Getting gnome-terminal via SSH and Xming

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty, gnome-terminal, xming

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox with a hosted network adapter, everything on Windows. I have set up openssh on Ubuntu listening to port 3220. I can log on successfully with PuTTY, I can run nautilus, gedit, etc. and get the GUI by Xming with no problem. Now when I run `gnome-terminal` I get an error

> Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Could not connect: Connection refused

I changed `DISPLAY` to several different possible values but none could work. Some SO answers suggest either `:0` or `:1`. Someone else suggested putting IP address in front of the column symbol, and I tried all. The default value in my system is `localhost:10.0`.

My question is: There are 3 display "numbers" present in my setting. Xming claims its server at `0.0`, PuTTY has a value in configuration (default when unset is `:0`), and Ubuntu (via SSH) has a variable `DISPLAY`. What are the relations between these numbers, and how should I coordinate them to get things work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been [a discussion](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/46374) in this issue. The following should work around the problem.

```
dbus-launch gnome-terminal
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error. A satisfactory solution is to press ALT-F2, type in xterm and execute the following:

```
dbus-update-activation-environment --all
```

Now, try running:

```
gnome-terminal
```

If it works fine, good. However, this will revert after reboot. You can make it permanent by adding it to /etc/profile.

```
echo "dbus-update-activation-environment --all" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
```

Now try running nautilus and gnome-terminal on boot up.