# Bash script that opens new terminal over ssh

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh

I am working on making a remote controlled vehicle and I connect to a Jetson with my laptop over WiFi. I have written a bash script to start each sub-process on the Jetson and plan to SSH from my laptop to the Jetson to run this script. Is there a way for me to see the new terminals this bash scripts opens so I can view the status of each system? BTW, both are running Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Do you `ssh` with the -X flag set? That forwards X11 displays to you over ssh.

Comment: @wxz I have tried that. Right now the Jetson is plugged into a monitor so I see the windows open on that screen but not on my laptop. Is it the 'gnome-terminal --' command I am using in the bash script that isn't fully compatible with X11?

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526553/457018) solve your issue?

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44786213/13020139) from SO, in which case, I'll mark this as a duplicate so this can be linked with the answer.

Comment: @wxz The first one works and seems to be more for the user by just adding export $(dbus-launch) to the main script before any gnome-terminal calls. Thank you very much, sorry for the duplicate

Comment: No worries. Not sure what the protocol is since the link that helped you wasn't from SO. I won't mark it as a duplicate and I'll let the mods figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

if you have xterm installed,then you can use the following command to open your
ssh session on another terminal :

```
xterm -e ssh root@*.*.*.*
```

if you don't have xterm installed then you can use one of the following :

```
gnome-terminal -- command

konsole -e command

terminal -e command
```

source : https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the